# loop through a list of names to pull files and assign to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a folder with different files of stock prices that I need to pull into python and then save to a dictionary. I'm trying to do this with a for loop and a list of names. Currently, when I run my code the console just sits there loading forever and never outputs anything or signals that it is done. This is what I currently have:

```
# Dictionary
results = {}
#Read in data from files (example: AAPL.txt)
tickers = ["AAPL", "ADBE", "DAL", "F", "GOOG", "GPRO", "NCLH", "NFLX", "RUN", "SBUX"]
for ticker in tickers:
    file = open("/user/code/"<ticker>".txt")
    lines = file.readlines()
    results["<ticker>_prices"].append(float(lines))

print(results)
```

This code doesn't even run, the console just runs and runs and the dictionary `results = {}` is still empty if I stop it and check.

Comment: There is no output action in your code.

Comment: The only action I would think this would require is to return the dictionary, I edited my example to show that at the end. However, it doesn't change what I'm seeing with the code not actually running to an end point.

Comment: do you have a file named `AAPL.txt` for example in your directory?

Comment: Yes, I have a file names AAPL.txt, ADBE.txt, DAL.txt, etc. One for each of the values in the tickers list

Comment: file = open("/user/code/" + ticker + ".txt")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should work. Since each `ticker` is a file name, you could open and read each file, then map each line to a float and assign to `results` under key `f"{ticker}_prices"`:

```
results = {}
for ticker in tickers:
    with open(f"/user/code/{ticker}.txt") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        results[f"{ticker}_prices"] = list(map(float, lines))
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following statement:

```py
for ticker in tickers:
    print("/user/code/"<ticker>".txt")
```

The output is all true.

Maybe you should do this:

```py
file = open("/user/code/" + ticker + ".txt")
```

Comment: That worked for the first part! It's running now, but now it's giving me an error at the end where it's not assigning it to a key and the list to the values of that key. I updated the end of my code with the same logic as what you provided: `results[ticker + "_prices"].append(float(lines))'